# How can i make incorporate a 'int only' input in this loop?

Tags: java

I've been messing around with this code for about an hour now trying to make it loop if the user inputs a character instead of a number

```
    System.out.println("Enter level student last completed (0-3): "); 
    int level = in.nextInt();
    while (level > 3 || level < 0){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid level!: ");
        level = in.nextInt();
    }
```

I thought of adding `!in.hasNextInt()` to the line `while (level > 3 || level < 0)` to make it

```
while (!in.hasNextInt() || level > 3 || level < 0)
```

but this doesn't help as the programme still crashes if a character is input.

edit:

```
    System.out.println("Enter level student last completed (0-3): "); 
    int level = 1; //in.nextInt();
    while (in.hasNextInt()==false || level > 3 || level < 0){
        in.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid level!: ");
    }
    level = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: Are you sure it crashes and doesn't hang? (i.e. is there an error message)

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
 at StudentData.main(StudentData.java:49)
`
is the error. But i dont understand what its implying.

Comment: i have seen your previous post also, i have gone through your code and request you to go through Java coding guidelines once, that will help you writing better code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a while loop to repeatedly ask for an input until it gets the kind it likes

### Basic solution

```
    int i;
    while(scan.hasNextInt()==false){ //keep asking until it gets something it likes
        scan.next(); //<--consume bad input, important!
        System.out.println("Only integers are valid");
    }
    i=scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println(i);
```

### Advanced solution

You can package this up into method which will make life easier when we want to incorporate more logic

```
public static int getSafeInteger(){
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); //if using scanner over and over consider passing the scanner as an argument
    while(scan.hasNextInt()==false){
        scan.next();
        System.out.println("Only integers are valid");
    }
    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

Then we can use that method within your existing loop

```
    System.out.println("Enter level");
    
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int level=getSafeInteger();
    while (level > 3 || level < 0){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid level!: ");
        level = getSafeInteger();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i was looking for! Something simple and compact.

Comment: How can i get this to only allow values (0-3) aswell, edit in OP

Comment: You're close but || is an OR statement so use && instead. Or alternatively look into ENUMS which is a structure that allows you to limit the allowable input: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Surely OR statements are correct, as AND would mean that it would have to be a character and also smaller/greater than the specified numbers?

Comment: @user3050340 OR statements are indeed correct, because your condition establishes *bad* inputs not *good* inputs. Regardless, see my edit for how you can use the existing "safe" version of the scanner within your existing logic

Answer (score 0):

Use `nextLine()` and try parsing it as an integer using `Integer.parseInt(String)` instead.

Comment: scanner.hasNextInt() does a better job here for checking if its an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int level;
while (true) {
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        // now we know at least the input is a number
        if (level > 3 || level < 0) {
            // aww, it's an invalid number :(
            in.nextLine(); // clear bad input
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid level (0-3)!: ");
        } else {
            // hooray! store the input now
            level = in.nextInt();
            break; // out of the infinite loop
        }
    } else {
        // input is not a number
        in.nextLine(); // clear bad input
        System.out.println("Please enter a number!: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int level;

System.out.printf("Enter level student last completed (0-3): "); 
while(true) {
    try {
        level = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        if (level < 4 && level > -1) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
    System.out.printf("Please enter a valid level!: ");
}
```

Comment: scanner.hasNextInt() is in this case a bit smoother for checking if the input is an integer

Comment: But he/she wants to loop and ask again for a correct int. So hasNextInt doesn't work here because it ends the loop.

Comment: @Sergi Thats why the loop's condition is `!sc.hasNextInt` or `sc.hasNextInt==false`, see [this example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20377156/2187042)

Answer (score 0):

you can set default value of level more than 3
and do following

```
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Enter level student last completed (0-3): ");
                try{
                 level = in.nextInt();
                }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("Not a valid Number");
                    in.nextLine();
                }
            }while (level > 3 || level < 0);
```